# How to find Jenkins projects don't have a particular step?

Tags: jenkins

e.g. we require all project to have the Delete Workspace step when build complete successfully. Now I want to list all projects hasn't included this step. How can I find them?

I see jobs has this step has this line in config.xml: . I can easily find the jobs have this step by search in /jobs folder with Notepad++, but not sure what's the best way to find those NOT have this step.

Answer (score 0):

If you have skills of Groovy, I suggest you take a look at this page [Display jobs group by the build steps they use](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Display+jobs+group+by+the+build+steps+they+use).

You can try this script by typing this code into http://your-jenkins-server-url/script

Comment: The script produces an empty result like this, not good enough in Groovy to fix it: Result: {org.jenkinsci.plugins.conditionalbuildstep.singlestep.SingleConditionalBuilder=[], com.hp.application.automation.tools.settings.AlmServerSettingsBuilder=[], com.hp.application.automation.tools.settings.MCServerSettingsBuilder=[], caphyon.jenkins.advinst.AdvinstBuilder=[], org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.repositoryconnector.ArtifactResolver=[], hudson.plugins.msbuild.MsBuildBuilder=[], org.jenkinsci.plugins.conditionalbuildstep.BuilderChain=[], org.jenkinsci.plugins.conditionalbuildstep.ConditionalBuilder=[],